# Commonality factoring (group compression, deduplication) of records in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, compression

Suppose I have 10,000 records in a database table, and each record contains a binary array that is 10 MB. Suppose that the documents don't compress much when run individually through a compressor, to keep the hypothetical simple.

Suppose that of the 10 MB per file, 1 MB is unique and independent, and the other 9MB is common among all 10,000 documents.

If I were to store all 10,000 objects in a single compressed file, it would be approximately (10,000 * 1MB) + 9MB of storage, or almost a 90% compression ratio. But by storing them individually in the database, commonality cannot be exploited.

1. Are there databases that do this factoring automatically for database columns?
2. I use MS SQL Server 2012. Is there a feature that does commonality factoring?
3. Supposing MSSQL does not do this, are there examples of c# code to make a custom compressor based on a corpus of binary files? I would generate a compressor based off a corpus manually for each large database table, then run the compressor before inserting a record, and insert the decompressor after reading it.

Comment: You could use FILESTREAM column and store the data in a compressed volume (in the file system).

Comment: The current trend is to use de-duplication technologies on the underlying storage array. Whether it will work with your database or not I do not know. You have to reaserch this bit. I am including a link that has some intro information from one of the vendors (ther are many to choose from): http://blog.purestorage.com/deduplication-compression-and-sql-server-databases-part-1/ .